# Execution order of onCreateUser, onLogin, validateLoginAttempt and registerLoginHandler

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am confused by the execution order of the following methods, which one got executed first and what is the correct order?

```
Accounts.onCreateUser
Accounts.onLogin
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt
Accounts.registerLoginHandler
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess most of you are watching super bowl now:)

I tried to sum it up.

Accounts.onCreateUser usually corresponds to "Sign Up" of your web page. It will create a user in your system.

Accounts.validateLoginAttempt: as implied by its name, it happens before "OnLogin" or "OnLoginFailure". "Accounts.validateLoginAttempt" will decide when your login succeeds or fails. Then it will pass information to "OnLogin" or "OnLoginFailure".

Accounts.validateNewUser: called before "Accounts.validateLoginAttempt".

Accounts.registerLoginHandler: one of login handlers. It is triggered before Accounts.OnLogin.